# Error while calling a method which passes request and response For storing a file to MYSQL databases

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, file-upload

i am developing a project KNOWLEDGE based community sharing system.
in which users can login and share their resources to other Users....

I'm getting a problem in uploading a file to mysql database....

PS..my Instructor strictly Says to use MVC architecture So, i have to use the same..
So i have created only one Servlet named Controller.java.
here i will redirect to other java programs for calculations...

Here is the code for Controller.java

```
package com.kbcss.controller;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.servlet.ServletConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import com.kbcss.command.LoginCommand;
import com.kbcss.command.Commands;
import com.kbcss.command.ResourceCommand;
import com.kbcss.command.UserCommand;

public class Controller extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public Controller() {super();}

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    private Map commands = new HashMap();

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException{
        super.init();

        System.out.println("i am in init");

        this.commands.put("login", new LoginCommand());
        this.commands.put("user", new UserCommand());
        this.commands.put("resource", new ResourceCommand());

        System.out.println("i am about to exit init");        
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        System.out.println("i am in doget");
        processCommand(request, response);
    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        System.out.println("i am in dopost");
        processCommand(request, response);
    }

    private void processCommand(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        System.out.println("i am in processCommand");

        String formAction = request.getParameter("form_action");

        System.out.println("i am in processCommand state 2");

        Commands command = (Commands) commands.get(formAction);     
                             command.execute(request, response);

        System.out.println("i am about to exit processCommand");
    }
}
```

and here is the code for saving the resources to MY database table.... Named **ResourceCommand .java**

```
package com.kbcss.command;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import com.oreilly.servlet.MultipartRequest;

public class ResourceCommand extends HttpServlet  implements Commands{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public void execute(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        try {

            //
            // JNDI to connect to database
            //
            Connection conn = null;
            Context initContext = new InitialContext();
            Context envContext = (Context)initContext.lookup("java:/comp/env");
            DataSource ds = (DataSource)envContext.lookup("jdbc/tia");
            conn = ds.getConnection();

            //
            // Save file(s) temporarily to filesystem
            //
            MultipartRequest multi = new MultipartRequest(request, "F:", 10*1024*1024);
            Enumeration files = multi.getFileNames();
            String filename = "";
            File f = null;

            while(files.hasMoreElements()) {
              String name = (String)files.nextElement();
              filename = multi.getFilesystemName(name);
              String type = multi.getContentType(name);
              f = multi.getFile(name);
            }

            //
            // Insert file into database
            //
            InputStream is = new FileInputStream(f);
            String sql = "INSERT INTO resource (`title`, `cat`, `user`, `filename`, `file`, `like`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"
;
            PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            // Set some Title
            stmt.setString(1, "some thing");
            // Set some category
            stmt.setString(2, ".net");
            // Set some user
            stmt.setString(3, "sri");
            // Set Filename
            stmt.setString(4, f.getName());
            // Set the data
            stmt.setBinaryStream(5, is, (int) f.length());
            // Set Likes
            stmt.setInt(6, 2);

            stmt.executeUpdate();
            is.close();

            //
            // Release connection
            //
            if (stmt != null) {
              try { stmt.close(); } catch (SQLException e) { ; }
              stmt = null;
            }
            if (conn != null) {
              try { conn.close(); } catch (SQLException e) { ; }
              conn = null;
            }
          } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
          }     
    }
}
```

And here is the **jSP file** where i will upload from....

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>UPLOAD FILE page</title></head>
<body>

<form method="post" action="Controller" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="form_action" value="resource" /> 
        <b>File to upload to database:</b>     
    <input type="file" name="attachment" size="36">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload">
</form>

</body></html>
```

And this is the error i'm getting :(

```
INFO: Reloading Context with name [/KBCSS] is completed
i am in init
i am about to exit init
i am in dopost
i am in processCommand
i am in processCommand state 2
Oct 10, 2013 11:29:59 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [Controller] in context with path [/KBCSS] threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.kbcss.controller.Controller.processCommand(Controller.java:69)
    at com.kbcss.controller.Controller.doPost(Controller.java:53)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

and by the way..i have created a **Command.java interface** here it is.

```
package com.kbcss.command;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

public interface Commands {

    public void execute(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException;

}
```

Can any one guide me PLZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ
i'm stuck for a day and Half and have no clue what i'm doing...

This is what happens if u ask an electrical engineering student to do a Java Project !!!!

***GREAT GREAT thanks from My side.....***

Answer (score 2):

Chances are that `commands.get(formAction);` is returning `null`, so `command` is also `null`. When you call `command.execute(request, response);`, you're trying to access something within a `null` object. That's going to get you a `NullPointerException`.

Use your print statements to determine what the exact value of `formAction` is when you get the exception. Then verify that you're putting a key for that string into `commands` (if it isn't `"login"`, `"user"`, or `"resource"`, since you're already entering those).

One other thing that may be causing the problem is that you need to add class-types to your `Map`. Change it to:

```
private Map<String,Command> commands = new HashMap<String,Command>();
```

After you do that, you shouldn't have to suppress the warning on the `Map`.

Comment: i tried a different approach..See here>> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19386352/send-a-file-from-jsp-to-controller-which-calls-a-method-of-interface-how-do-i-u I am afraid that new approach is also not Working..