# Send a file from JSP to controller which calls a method of interface -How do I upload a file from that request?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, file-upload

hello every one i'm working on a project.

Hope u can help me in solving my problem.. I'm struggling for 5 DAYS!!

in a module which is assigned to me I have to upload a file, title, category, uploadedby details from a JSP to controller.do which stores the `request` and `responce` in a method named `execute()` which is present in `Command.java` **Interface**.

now when i pass all the Upload form details,, it goes all the way across to a class named `ResourceCommand.java implements Command` which calls a DAO and stops execution in middle !!!!

part of code from **Upload.jsp**

```
<form name="myform_up" method="post" action = "Controller">  
         <input type="hidden" name="form_action" value="resource" /> 
         <input type="hidden" name="action" value="insert" />
   <table>      
         <tr>
            <td>Document Title <font color="red">*</font></td></tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" name="name" /></td></tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Category <font color="red">*</font>
            <select name="cat">
                <option value="Java" selected >Java Material</option>
                <option value="Net">.Net Material</option>
                <option value="C">C and C# Material</option>
            </select></td>
        </tr>
            <input type="hidden" name="uploadedby" value="<jsp:getProperty name="userBean" property="user" />" />
        <tr>
            <td>Upload A file:
            <input type="file" name="file1"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><br/><input type="checkbox" name="t_condition" checked />I Had received Copyrights for this Document</td>
        </tr>
        <TR>
            <td ALIGN="CENTER"><br/>
            <INPUT class="button blue" TYPE="submit" value="Upload" /> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <INPUT class="button red" TYPE="reset" value="Clear" />
            </td></TR>
    </TABLE>
</FORM>
```

part of code from **Controller.java**

```
public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException{
        super.init();

        System.out.println("i am in init");

        this.commands.put("login", new LoginCommand());
        this.commands.put("resource", new ResourceCommand());

    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        System.out.println("i am in doget");
        processCommand(request, response);
    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        System.out.println("i am in dopost");
        processCommand(request, response);
    }

    private void processCommand(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        String formAction = request.getParameter("form_action");
System.out.println("implementing formAction = " + formAction);
        Commands command = (Commands) commands.get(formAction);     
                             command.execute(request, response);            
    }
}
```

part of code from **ResourceCommand.java**

```
public class ResourceCommand extends HttpServlet  implements Commands{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public void execute(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        if ("insert".equalsIgnoreCase(request.getParameter("action"))) {
            this.addResource(request, response);
        }
    }

    private void addResource(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException{

        ResourceBean ResourceBean = new ResourceBean();
        mapToResourceBeans(request, ResourceBean);

        String result = null;
        try {
            result = new ResourceDAO().uploadResource(request, ResourceBean);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.err.println(" Error in inserting new resource");
        }
        if ("success".equalsIgnoreCase(result)) {
                       // if Block CODE
        }

        else {
                       //Else block CODE
        }       
    }
    private void mapToResourceBeans(HttpServletRequest request,
            ResourceBean ResourceBean) {        
        ResourceBean.setName(request.getParameter("name"));
        ResourceBean.setCat(request.getParameter("cat"));
        ResourceBean.setUploadedby(request.getParameter("uploadedby"));             
    }   
}
```

part of code from **Command.java**

```
public interface Commands {

    public void execute(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException;

}
```

part of code from **ResourceDAO.java**

```
public class ResourceDAO {
        static final String SUCCESS = "success";
        static final String FAILURE = "failure";

        static Logger log = Logger.getLogger("com.a");

        public String uploadResource(HttpServletRequest request,
                ResourceBean newResource) throws FileNotFoundException {

            String result = null;
            PreparedStatement stmtInsert = null;    
            // Create a Database Connection
            Connection con = ConnectionDAO.getJDBCConnection();
            try {
            PreparedStatement pstmt = con
                        .prepareStatement("INSERT INTO resource(name, cat, uploadedby, file) values(?,?,?,?)");
                pstmt.setString(1, newResource.getName());
    System.out.println(newResource.getName());

                pstmt.setString(2, newResource.getCat());
    System.out.println(newResource.getCat());

                pstmt.setString(3, newResource.getUploadedby());
    System.out.println(newResource.getUploadedby());

                String file = request.getParameter("file1");
    System.out.println("0");

                File f = new File(file);
    System.out.println("1");

                FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
    System.out.println("2");

                pstmt.setBinaryStream(4, fis, (int) f.length());
    System.out.println("3");    
                int rows = pstmt.executeUpdate();

                result = SUCCESS;

                if (rows != 1) { result = FAILURE; }

            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                result = FAILURE;
                ConnectionDAO.rollbackJDBCConnection(con);
                ex.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                ConnectionDAO.commitJDBCConnection(con);
                ConnectionDAO.closeStatement(stmtInsert);
                ConnectionDAO.closeJDBCConnection(con);
            }
            return result;
        }    
    }
```

Console Display..

```
implementing formAction = resource
 Error in inserting new resource
123
Net
null
0
1
i am going back to addResource page
```

If i place   `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in form TAG.. then i will get this..

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    com.kbcss.controller.Controller.processCommand(Controller.java:57)
    com.kbcss.controller.Controller.doPost(Controller.java:49)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
```

**I am completely LOST..Plz HELP...**

Comment: Have you read this Q/A: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2422468/1065197?

Comment: i have..but by problem includes passing the request from class to class and then to an interface...By the way there is only one Servlet(Controller.java) that's it. rest are just classes..

Comment: If you're working with Serlvet 2.5 or prior, you should not use `request.getParameter` when processing `<form enctype="multipart/form-data">`. This is noted in the Q/A linked above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found out that i should use Serlvet 3.0 to make thing work..
I thank u all for giving some of u'r  effort to my code :p ...

Answer (score 1):

Is this line 56? The one before the error?

```
Commands command = (Commands) commands.get(formAction);
```

It may be returning `null` if the command isn't found in the `commands` map (which you didn't show). You should at least check for a valid command being returned from the map.

A `Map` will return `null` when something isn't found to match. On the next line you use it and would get a `NullPointerException`.